# How do I spawn a new process to do a task in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I would like to write a Ruby script that runs a daemon Ruby process, so that I can do something like the following:

```
$ task start
Started...

# start a daemon to do useful work; don't block

# Some time later:
$ task end
Finished.
```

What's the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `Process.daemon` method when you want your process to detach from the terminal and stop being able to send output. To end the process, you will have to send it a signal. Most programs handle this by using a file that contains the PID.